# Getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3' on Apache web server when running python script

Tags: python-3.x, server, apache2, boto3, modulenotfounderror

I'm using AWS EC2 which is running apache2, and I have a python script that uses boto3. The python script runs with no error when I execute it in the command line, but when I try to run it in the web browser, I get a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3'. I've tried the following solutions but nothing worked:

- pip3 is up to date.
- I tried `pip3 install --user boto3` but it says I already have boto3 installed.
- I tried using the `addsitedir` function from the `site` module.

Here is the code for my python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
print("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8")
print("Content-type:text/html\r\n")
print("\<H1> Hello, From python server :) </H1>")
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
import site
site.addsitedir('/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages')
import math
import boto3 #ModuleNotFound error occurs
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Probably you are using python 2, not 3, to run the script.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I have python3 installed and run it that way. Are you saying when it runs in the web browser it uses python2?

Comment: Just a guess. Make make sure that you are using correct version of python in apache.

Comment: I have the correct version. Python 3.10.4